# recievedMessage not defined?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot for a few of my friends, and I'm getting the following error upon execution: 'recievedMessage is not defined'. What do I have to change/add? I'm removing the token for safety purposes.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()
const MessageAttchment = require('discord.js');


client.on('message', (receivedMessage) => {
    // Prevent bot from responding to its own messages
    if (receivedMessage.author == client.user) {
        return
    }
    
    // Check if the bot's user was tagged in the message
    if (receivedMessage.content.includes(client.user.toString())) {
        // Send acknowledgement message
        receivedMessage.channel.send("Juan?")
    }
})

client.on('message', receivedMessage => {
    if (receivedMessage.content.content === 'Si') {
        const localFileAttachment = new Discord.Attachment('juan.jpg')
        generalChannel.send(localFileAttachment)
    }
  });
    if (receivedMessage.content.content === 'No') {
        receivedMessage.channel.send('text here')
    }

client.login("XXXXX") // Replace XXXXX with your bot token
```

Comment: `recievedMessage` is that your exact error message, or a typo?

Comment: @GuerricP must have been a typo of mine

Comment: Nevermind, Ramesh Kithsiri HettiArachchi found your mistake

Answer (score 1):

The error is throwing from below line.

```js
if (receivedMessage.content.content === 'No') {
```

Because there is no `receivedMessage` in the outer scope. I think you closed the callback scope at the wrong place. Change the code as following snippet.

```js
client.on('message', receivedMessage => {
    if (receivedMessage.content.content === 'Si') {
        const localFileAttachment = new Discord.Attachment('juan.jpg')
        generalChannel.send(localFileAttachment)
    }


    if (receivedMessage.content.content === 'No') {
        receivedMessage.channel.send('text here')
    }
  });
```

Comment: Also- it's just `Message#content`, not `Message#content#content`